# Visual Studio define pre-processor directive in the command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

```
#ifdef DEBUG_TEST
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
#endif
```

How can I `#define DEBUG_TEST` as a command line argument in VS? I have tried `/DDEBUG_TEST`and the directive does not get defined.

Comment: Where did you add `/DDEBUG_TEST`? That works on the `cl` command line, but if you enter it in the VS IDE under Preprocessor Definitions then you need to enter just `DEBUG_TEST`.

Comment: why not just use the preprocessor section.... updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

not sure if its a formatting problem in your question, but this should work :-

```
 /D "DEBUG_TEST"
```

or enter it in the preprocessor section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
/DDEBUG_TEST
```

No space, no quotation marks.  I believe you can also use gcc syntax with cl, but I'm not sure.  If so, this should also work:

```
-DDEBUG_TEST
```

Example usage:

```
cl /DDEBUG_TEST source_code.cpp
```

Here's the official documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx

Comment: I have looked at the MS documentation and it does not work.

Comment: @JamesKing Are you running `cl` from the visual studio command prompt?  Because `/Dmacro_name[=value]` is the correct syntax for `cl`, and I use it when compiling programs.

Comment: I enter it in the Command line arguements box in the properties.

Comment: Which command line box, and which version of visual studio?  I see a few boxes (one for the linker, one for the manifest tool, etc.), so it might be in the wrong one (note that my version of VStudio is a bit outdated, yours might be different than mine).  See the first section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3600tzxa.aspx , and make sure it's in the box specified there?

Comment: Specifically, it should be in the Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line section, I believe, that appears to be the one that passes arguments to `cl`.  Try entering the option there, and see if it works.

Comment: I used the Command line arguements box under the Debugging tab.

Comment: Ah, there's the problem.  That's where you enter arguments to pass to the program you're debugging itself, not to the compiler.  Go to C/C++ > Command Line and try entering it there instead.